# Query for latest date for each unique value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `atm` table and `replenishment` table both have the same `atm_id`, `atm.ATM_id  = replenishment.atm_id`.

So I want to get back every `atm.title`. `atm.ATM_id` with its last `replenishment.rep_datetime`.

Trying to find what did I miss. Thank you for your help

I tried this one

```
select distinct atm.ATM id, atm.title, cash added1, cash added2, cash added3, cash added4,rep_datetime
from replenishment
inner join atm on atm.ATM_id = replenishment.atm_id
where rep_datetime = (select max(rep_datetime) from replenishment)
order by rep_datetime DESC
```

Any ideas on this one noting that the result gets one record with the latest date for single value but what I want is to have all ids with their latest date.

Expecting all ids without duplications with their latest/newest date.

Comment: You need a _correlated_ subquery.

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting products, please only tag the product you are *really* using. I've removed the conflicting tags, you'll need to [edit] your question to (re)tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: i dont get it for the correlated subquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: The query you've given us isn't valid; `select max(rep_datetime from replenishment)` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: A group by and max aggregate should be all you need here, no?

Comment: That would give the `MAX` values, not the latest row, @ClearlyClueless . I can (and will) close this as a duplicate once we know what product the OP is really using, but they've thus far ignored that [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77685314/sql-query-for-latest-date-for-each-unique-value#comment136956702_77685314).

Comment: I hadn't quite read the whole question or looked at his query. He would need some CTE or subquery to accomplish what he is after. Carry on. Off to the next question.

Comment: forgot to complete the parentheses

Comment: Actually tried group by but gave me an error

Comment: @ClearlyClueless. so how would the query go and if you don’t mind link the other question that could be same as mine to have my question tagged as duplicate

Comment: Why are you selecting the `cash` column four times with different aliases? If makes me wonder if the existing query is really doing what you think.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it gets back one record with the latest date only not every id with its latest date as expected

Comment: @siggemannen i guess not and apologize for replying late just now reviewing the comments but thanks for referring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a windowing function for this:

```
SELECT ATM_id, atm.title, cash_added1, cash_added2, cash_added3, cash_added4, rep_datetime
FROM (
    select atm.ATM_id, atm.title, rep_datetime
        , cash_added1, cash_added2, cash_added3, cash_added4
        , row_number() over (partition by atm.atm_id order by rep_datetime desc) rn
    from atm 
    inner join replenishment r on atm.ATM_id = r.atm_id
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i will give that a try hope it works with me

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.Atm_id, a.title, 
-- ...
r.repDate
from atm a
inner join
(select atm_id, max(rep_datetime) as repDate 
  from replenishment group by atm_id) r
on a.ATM id = r.atm_id
order by r.repDate DESC;
```

Comment: I think the cash columns also come from the replenishment table, which means won't work. Though it sure would be nice if the OP was clearer about that.

Comment: sorry about that, yes you are correct the cash added and date coming from replenishment table and the ATM_id and the title coming from the atm table

Comment: thank you btw for the answer i will give it a try as well

Comment: @Joel, then it simply takes another join on replenishment to get those (r.atm_id = rp.atm_id and r.repDate = rp.rep_datetime). It was not clear what those were.